# Async in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array of models where I have the type and key.

```
models = [{type: 'user', key: getKey('user')},    
    //.
    //.Many more model objects here
    //.
    {type: 'employee',  key: getKey('employee')}];
```

Here I'm mapping each of the model to my search function which gets data for each model:

```
async.map(models, search, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        res.json(400, err);
    } else {
        // Here results is an array of arrays of different results for different models and I dont know how to check
        // how to find different models with the same key and union their results if they have the same key value...
        var mergedResult = [];
        mergedResult = mergedResult.concat.apply(mergedResult, results);
        res.json(200, mergedResult);
    }
});
```

And Here is my search function which returns for passed model name:

```
function search(model, callback) {
    getData(model.type, callback);
}
```

So now I'm getting the result for each model (user, customer,... and employee), but now I want to check if any of these models have the same key which I get by getKey(modelName) function; in our example lets say the key for user and employee is the same and it is "name" field, so in this case I want to union (like the union in sql) the results of employee and user:
lets say for "user" we get:

**Results for user model:**

```
[
    {
        name : "Mike",
        age: 33
        eyeColor: "brown"
    },
    {
        name : "David",
        age: 35
    }
]
```

and for employee we get :

**Results for Employee model:**

```
    [
        {
            name : "Mike",
            age: 33,
            heigh: 178,
            eyeColor: "black"
        },
        {
            name : "Nanacy",
            age: 39
        }
    ]
```

**The desired results:**

```
[
    {
        name : "Mike",
        age: 33
        eyeColor: "brown",
        heigh: 178
    },
    {
        name : "David",
        age: 35
    },
    {
        name : "Nanacy",
        age: 39
    }
]
```

In my algorithm I'm just simply returning:

**What I'm returning:**

```
[
    {
        name : "Mike",
        age: 33
        eyeColor: "brown"
    },
    {
        name : "David",
        age: 35
    },
    {
        name : "Mike",
        age: 33,
        heigh: 178,
        eyeColor: "black"
    },
    {
        name : "Nanacy",
        age: 39
    }
]
```

Please let me know if I you need more calrification!
Thanks

Comment: Do have any actual problems with `async`? Could you have solved the problem if the functions were synchronous? If so, please show us that (pseudo-)code, it might be easier to understand than your text.

Comment: Map through `Object.keys`/`[].keys()` instead

Comment: @Bergi Thanks man! I guess I simplified my question; I hope this makes more sense; I'm just looking for the same functionality as union of mysql; my search function is giving back the results for each model...

Comment: @vp_arth Thanks man! but in this case Object.keys would be just the index number?! Could you please elaborate your solution...

Comment: `async.map` retains the order of the items. `results[0]` will be the result of `getData(models[0].type)` and so on. With that information, you can simply loop the models to determine in what order which result sets should be merged on what key, and then just reference each result set by its index. Your "union" algorithm is a bit underspecified though, so you'll have to figure that out yourself (e.g. how it would deal with the data if Mike's age would be different in the two results).

Comment: @Bergi Right, but inside async.map I dont have access to the key for each model results; in other words I dont know what was the key for results[0]  and what was the key for results[1], right? If get the key for each result, it solves my problem! I guess async.each would solve my problem! Not sure yet!

Comment: I missed, that you have different order in getData results, how your records identified as same? is `name` field unique? what key are you seek? Is it `models[i].key`?

Comment: @Bergi  how it would deal with the data if Mike's age would be different in the two results)?
Answer: In my algorithm order of the models is important, if the value for some fields for items with the same key are different the first model should overwite the other ones!

Comment: @vp_arth name is the key in my example and each results set (user, employee) there is just one in each model

Comment: Other words key field is `getData(model.type, function(err, data){data[model.key]})` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should save `key` about info, while you have it:

```
function search(model, next) {
  var data = getData(model.type, function(err, data){
     if (err) return next(err);
     data['__key'] = data[model.key];
     next(null, data)
  });
}
```